How can I run ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app with Docker?
I trying to execute a web app with Docker, the container is running successfully:
app
But when I try to open localhost:53021, this error appears:
error
My launchsettings.json:
enter image description here
My appsettings.json:
enter image description here
My docker-compose:
services:
   auth_fiscal_io:
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: ./auth.fiscal.io/Dockerfile
      networks:
         - auth
      environment:
         - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
         - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      ports:
         - "53021:80"
      container_name: auth_fiscal_io

networks:
   auth:

my dockerfile:
    #See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Nuget.config", "."]
COPY ["auth.fiscal.io/auth.fiscal.io.csproj", "auth.fiscal.io/"]
COPY ["data.fiscal.io/data.fiscal.io.csproj", "data.fiscal.io/"]
COPY ["util.fiscal.io/util.fiscal.io.csproj", "util.fiscal.io/"]
COPY ["srv.fiscal.io/srv.fiscal.io.csproj", "srv.fiscal.io/"]
COPY ["pay.fiscal.io/pay.fiscal.io.csproj", "pay.fiscal.io/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./auth.fiscal.io/./auth.fiscal.io.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/auth.fiscal.io"
RUN dotnet build "./auth.fiscal.io.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
RUN dotnet publish "./auth.fiscal.io.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "auth.fiscal.io.dll"]

I appreciate anyone who can help me.
I'm trying to open an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app, I expect it to be running successfully.

You appear to be using a Docker base image for .NET Core 2.2  - that's really out-of-date and unsupported. You need to update that, and that's probably the cause of your problem...

The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6. Since .NET 7 you can publish directly to a Docker image. Notice how someone answered mentioning port 80 because they can't see what the dockerfile contains

Please post text as text, not images. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. Had you posted the dockerfile as text the problems would be immediately obvious

this could be a newbie question , have you tried exposing both ports saperately and checking if it runs ?
as in
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 53021
and in yaml file

"53021:53021"
"80:80"
and check where its hosting ?


which csproj has your ".exe" (or whatever "top layer")?     "io.dll" just .. my eyeball opinion, looks off.

Check your Dockerfile and be sure you are exposing port 80.
Additionally, you can check your logs to see if there is an issue with your application.
docker compose -f docker-compose-file.yml logs


You can share your Dockerfile here if you don't mind
